# Android Broadcastlistener to start from code at some specifc event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

As described in question I want to start a broadcast receiver on some event say a button click so I don't want to use it in xml. Any idea how to do this I searched on net but most of example are using xml for this

Regard's 
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code to your button onClick listener. It creates a receiver, handler, and intent filter, sets the action your receiver should be registered for and register it. Dont' forget to unregister it after all the work will be done.

```
// this goes before onCreate()
    private static final String ACTION = "YOUR_ACTION_HERE";
/// in button listener:
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Handle reciever
        String mAction = intent.getAction();

        if(mAction.equals(ACTION) {
          // Do your thing   
        }
    }
    IntentFilter intentToReceiveFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentToReceiveFilter.addAction(ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentToReceiveFilter, null, mHandler);
```

Comment: sorry If ask a stupid question but I had to listen for incoming sms and I already extends a class for it and overrided its onCreate does this work in that situation also

Comment: of course. And, generally, nothing stops you from checking it right now.

Comment: its giving me this
The method registerReceiver(SMSReceiver, IntentFilter, null, Handler) is undefined for the type new Handler(){}

I used following code
SMSReceiver mSmsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentToReceiveFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentToReceiveFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    this.registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, intentToReceiveFilter, null, mHandler);

Comment: This is the error that I am getting on register receiver line " The method registerReceiver(SMSReceiver, IntentFilter, null, Handler) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"
I had used the same syntax that you told me